# How to perform "mkdir" and "move" operations in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

just wondering if anyone could show me how to do a couple simple commands with VB.net syntax that I can do with DOS or batch files.

For example...
What would be the equivalent of

```
SET date="%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%"
mkdir E:%date%
move C:\folder *.png E:\%date%
```

Thats just a simple DOS or batch command to make a directory with the date, and to move all .png files into that folder.

I need to know how to do `mkdir` and `move`. The part where I create the dated folder would be cool, but isn't necessary.

Comment: Why not use something like Powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This chunk of code should match your script.

```
Dim dateText As String = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
Dim toPath As String = Path.Combine("E:", dateText)
Directory.CreateDirectory(toPath)
For Each (filename As String In Directory.GetFiles("C:\folder", "*.png"))
    File.Move(filename, toPath)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) namespace. In particular the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) and [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) classes.

To get the current date in a string you can use in the directory name have a look at the ToString method on the DateTime struct.